# How to rotate my player hand top and bottom with limit of 45 degrees.? unity 5

Tags: c#, rotation, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a 2d game in Unity. My game player have some features same like doodle army. I want to rotate my player hands and head with limits to 45 degree up and down like doodle army player both side. I am using two joystick one for movement and second for aiming targets. so second joystick can rotate the hand and head in direction of joystick movement. I want to limit this rotation to up and down 45 degrees both side(left and right (up and down)).

Any one can Help me.

Here is my little code to rotate 2d sprite arms and head.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput;

public class PlayerRotation : MonoBehaviour {

    public float moveForce = 5, boostMultiplier = 2;
    GameObject ga;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        ga = GameObject.Find ("Charac_Head");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate () {

        Vector2 moveVec = new Vector2 (CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis ("Horizontal2"), 
                              CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis ("Vertical2")) * moveForce;



        //ga.transform.LookAt(transform.position.toVector2() + moveVec);
            //ga.transform.Rotate (0, 0, moveVec.y);
        if (moveVec.y <= 4.0f && moveVec.y >= -4.0f) {
            //ga.transform.right = moveVec;
            ga.transform.Rotate(0,0,moveVec.y);
            Debug.Log (moveVec);
        }
        //}
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Mathf.Clamp to enforce final value between min and max.

I no test the code but i show you what you need:

```
moveVec.y = Mathf.Clamp(moveVec.y + Time.deltaTime*rotateRate, -45.0f, 45.0f);
transform.localEulerAngles = moveVec;
```

Comment: I will try this.